# How to get a file daily via SFTP using Spring Integration with Java config?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-java-config, spring-retry

I need to get a file daily via SFTP. I would like to use Spring Integration with Java config. The file is generally available at a specific time each day. The application should try to get the file near that time each day. If the file is not available, it should continue to retry for x attempts. After x attempts, it should send an email to let the admin know that the file is still not available on the SFTP site.

One option is to use `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`. In the `MessageHandler`, I can kick off a job to process the file. However, I really don't need synchronization with the remote file system. After all, it is a scheduled delivery of the file. Plus, I need to delay at most 15 minutes for the next retry and to poll every 15 minutes seems a bit overkill for a daily file. I guess that I could use this but would need some mechanism to send email after a certain time elapsed and no file was received.

The other option seems to be using `get` of the SFTP Outbound Gateway. But the only examples I can find seem to be XML config.

**Update**

Adding code after using help provided by Artem Bilan's answer below:

Configuration class:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup="true", channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller("pollerMetadata"))
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource sftpMessageSource(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store) {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(applicationProperties));
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter local = new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store,"test");
    source.setLocalFilter(local);
    source.setCountsEnabled(true);        
    return source;
}

@Bean
public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata() {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    List<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<Advice>();
    adviceChain.add(retryCompoundTriggerAdvice());
    pollerMetadata.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(compoundTrigger());
    return pollerMetadata;
}

@Bean
public RetryCompoundTriggerAdvice retryCompoundTriggerAdvice() {
    return new RetryCompoundTriggerAdvice(compoundTrigger(), secondaryTrigger());
}

@Bean
public CompoundTrigger compoundTrigger() {
    CompoundTrigger compoundTrigger = new CompoundTrigger(primaryTrigger());
    return compoundTrigger;
}

@Bean
public Trigger primaryTrigger() {
    return new CronTrigger("*/60 * * * * *");
}

@Bean
public Trigger secondaryTrigger() {
    return new PeriodicTrigger(10000);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler(PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store) {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            store.flush();
        }

    };
}
```

RetryCompoundTriggerAdvice class:

```
public class RetryCompoundTriggerAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

    private final CompoundTrigger compoundTrigger;

    private final Trigger override;

    private int count = 0;

    public RetryCompoundTriggerAdvice(CompoundTrigger compoundTrigger, Trigger overrideTrigger) {
        Assert.notNull(compoundTrigger, "'compoundTrigger' cannot be null");
        this.compoundTrigger = compoundTrigger;
        this.override = overrideTrigger;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
        if (result == null && count <= 5) {
            count++;
            this.compoundTrigger.setOverride(this.override);
        }
        else {
            this.compoundTrigger.setOverride(null);
            if (count > 5) {
                 //send email
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Integration 4.3 there is `CompoundTrigger`:

```
* A {@link Trigger} that delegates the {@link #nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext)}
* to one of two Triggers. If the {@link #setOverride(Trigger) override} trigger is
* {@code null}, the primary trigger is invoked; otherwise the override trigger is
* invoked.
```

With the combination of `CompoundTriggerAdvice`:

```
* An {@link AbstractMessageSourceAdvice} that uses a {@link CompoundTrigger} to adjust
* the poller - when a message is present, the compound trigger's primary trigger is
* used to determine the next poll. When no message is present, the override trigger is
* used.
```

it can be used to reach your task:

The `primaryTrigger` can be a `CronTrigger` to run the task only once a day.

The `override` could be a `PeriodicTrigger` with desired short period to retry.

The `retry` logic you can utilize with one more `Advice` for poller or just extend that `CompoundTriggerAdvice` to add `count` logic to send an email eventually.

Since there is no file, therefore no message to kick the flow. And we don't have choice unless dance around the poller infrastructure.

Comment: `@Poller` has `value()` to accept `PollerMetadata` bean name. And there you can configure the `trigger`, `maxMessagesPerPoll` and `adviceChain` with desired `CompoundTriggerAdvice`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations and search for `@Poller`

Comment: Thanks. I found that documentation right after posting the comment and then deleted my comment, but apparently you still received / saw my comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: Glad to be helpful! So, it's time to accept my answer and let other people know that we have a solution here! And we will be free to do our own work :)

Comment: Almost done. Just trying to work through extending `CompoundTriggerAdvice` to implement the `retry` with `count` logic.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I'm sure that I'm missing something but was unable to extend `CompoundTriggerAdvice` since its `CompoundTrigger` and `Trigger` are private. Instead, I extended `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`. I notice though that once I set the override polling continues to occur using the override even once I set the override back to null after receiving a null `Message<?> result`. I noticed this same behavior with `CompoundTriggerAdvice`. Once the override is set, polling will be based on the override trigger even if a subsequent non-null `Message<?> result` is received.

Comment: Well, you can just borrow some idea from the `CompoundTriggerAdvice` and implement your own `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`. Sorry, I didn't think properly about the solution for you, so just sharing ideas where and how to dig.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing but I guess I don't understand how `CompoundTrigger` works to dynamically set polling. I figured setting its override to null would allow the polling to resume using the primary. But it doesn't. Once the override is set (in `afterReceive`), it is forever locked to poll using that trigger.

Comment: Well, `CompoundTriggerAdvice` does it basing on the `null` result, but you can switch to the `primary` back to any other required condition.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I see the same behavior using `CompoundTriggerAdvice`. So, perhaps there some other issue with my configuration. I'm going to update the OP with my code. I greatly appreciate your continued help.

Comment: I've noticed that after `afterReceive` is called with a non-null `result`, it is immediately called again. That seems to be causing the issue because on that immediate next call the `result` is null and so override trigger is set again.

Comment: I found the issue. Multiple messages were being generated per poll. The first message contained a non-null `result` and the very next message (presumably from the same poll) contained a null `result`. Once I set the max message per poll to one, the issue went away. I had it set with the annotation but forgot to set it when moving to Java config. Sorry that I missed that. Thanks again for your help. I accepted your answer. (I also upvoted it and your first comment.)